# Update url without refreshing page in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Currently i am using chrome.tabs.update to change the url of a page, and in some cases the fact that it instantly refreshes is really nice. However sometimes id like to not refresh the page and just change the url. From what I've been reading in google's documentation i have been unable to find such a method.

--Is there a way to change a url without refreshing the page in a chrome extension?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a simple task. Using the default `chrome.tabs` API you cannot change the tab url without an auto reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API functions directly in the content script.

So, you may send a message to the content script asking for url updating without changing page. The js line to be executed is like:

```
window.history.pushState("State Object", "Title", "newUrl");
```

Comment: I'm putting it like this ```window.history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);``` but its not working :(